# Can I retrieve missing Bitcoins that failed to process as Wallet is corrupt?

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions, wallet.dat, wallet-recovery, lost-bitcoins, lost-transactions

I have been using an old wallet until last year - Bitcoin Version v0.8.5-beta. QT Version 4.8.3.

I stopped using it as it has become corrupt. I had made several transactions that were not successful before I realized it was corrupt. They are showing in my transactions list as a question mark with 0 confirmations, however the transaction amount has been deducted from my wallet total.

I backed up the wallet.dat file after each transaction and overwrote the previous backup when I did this.

Can I retrieve the missing bitcoins?

Comment: Have you used https://blockchain.info to check the status of those transactions?  You'll need the transaction ID.

Comment: I checked blockchain.info at the time. It showed for an hour or so as pending ( or holding ) then disappeared. It never got into that system. I'm going from memory so cant remember the actual term it used for pending transaction

Comment: If you check blockchain.info *now* with one of the "missing" transaction IDs, what shows up?

Comment: Thanks for getting back. Sorry for the delay in answering - I have been away. I made 4 failed transactions - Three transactions show as zero transactions on Blockchain. The other one shows as 2 transactions and that it was received by the address that I sent it to. But it shows as having 0 confirmations in my wallet. The company that I sent it to said that they didn't receive it.

Comment: Hi Max. Further to my earlier comment. The one transaction that shows as being received by the address I sent it to - I sent the payment to them on 14 June 2016. Blockchain shows it being processed much later. The red debit transaction was dated 2016-12-09 and the green part of the transaction was dated 2016-10-17

Answer (score 1):

If you know the password to your wallet.dat, you should try to retrieve the private key adresses and import them in a wallet such as Electrum, and see if that fixes your issue.

This is a bit of a hassle when you have lots of changeadresses though, but it is better then not being able to access your funds.

When you unlocked your wallet.dat in bitcoin core, simply go to the console and

Use

> listreceivedbyaddress 0 true

OR, if you have generated new change adresses

> bitcoind listaddressgroupings

To get a list of all the adresses that you are currently using / have balance.

Then,

> walletpassphrase "your walletpassphrase here" 600
>   dumpprivkey [your Bitcoin address here]

OR, you could dump all the private keys at once, if you were using alot of different adresses using the following command:

> dumpwallet

And import these keys in a wallet such as electrum.

See if this resolves your issue.

Comment: Thanks I'll try that. Once I have entered dumpprivkey [my bitcoin address] where does the key show for me to import from? Thanks

Comment: `dumpprivkey` shows the key on-screen.  `dumpwallet` creates a text file (you specify the name) containing all the private keys.